# Multiple level ordering in Yii

Tags: sql-order-by, yii

This is my CActiveDataProvider

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider ('MyTable', array ( 
            'pagination' => array ( 
                    'PageSize' => 4, 
                ),
            'criteria' => array ( 
                    'condition' => 'from_user_id='.$user->id,
                    'order' => 'date DESC', 
                ), 
            ));
```

My question is: I would like to have this CActiveDataProvider ordered **first** by date (as the posted code does), and in a second level, within those with the same date, order by a second criteria. Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe I'm not understanding you correctly, but won't the following work? :

'order' => 'date DESC, name DESC',

Comment: EXACTLY!!!! I didn't know you could provide more than one ordering criteria like that. Thank you very much!!